# Run windows CMD in R

Tags: r, windows, cmd, rstudio

I am a beginner at R. If this question sounds childish to you then pardon me.

I need to run the following command in `R studio` by using Windows `CMD`.

```
copy *.txt combinedfiles.txt
```

This command actually combines all the files into one file in Windows `CMD`.

I tried using `system()` and `system2()`. But I could not get the results.
e.g.:

```
system(cmd.exe copy *.txt combinedfiles.txt)
```

Kindly help me out with this problem.

Comment: `cmd /c <command>`. See `cmd /?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy` is not a standalone program, but a builtin command of the Windows commandline interpreter. To run this, use `shell` in R.

```
shell("copy *.txt combinedfiles.txt")
```